# Convert web-scraped html polygon coords to lat/lon in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, coordinates

I'm trying to scrape the MNDOT website for road conditions using BeautifulSoup. I'm able to get a description of each road section using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests
url = "https://lb.511mn.org/mnlb/winterdriving/routeselect.jsf?view=state&text=m&textOnly=false"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')

soup
areas = soup.find_all('area')

output = {
    'Description' : [],
    'Coords' : []
}
for i in areas:
    d = i.attrs
    if 'coords' in d:
        output['Description'].append(d['alt'])
        output['Coords'].append([int(s) for s in d['coords'].split(",")])

# As an example:
print(output['Coords'][3])
```

At the time of writing this, the print statement outputs this list of coordinates, which I know are x,y pairs:
[381,
328,
380,
329,
383,
332,
383,
335,
386,
335,
388,
337,
389,
336,
388,
335,
388,
330,
383,
330,
381,
328]

**Is it possible to determine what latitudes/longitudes those would correspond to?**

Comment: If I understand you correctly: you want to print `Description` together with `Coords`?

Comment: I don't think easily. The polygon co-ords are relative to the map on the screen I think. If that is the case you would have to do some kinda of estimation perhaps based on centroid. Feels icky. Wonder if they produce related shape files you could use? There are also some invalid polygons listed e.g. `373,333,373,343,375,343,375,341,378,341,378,336,375,336,375,333` though it seems likely those account for the sticky out bits of unclosed _"polygons"_

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/270396/determine-exact-coordinates-for-a-map-image